# Display image instead of text when text contains two words

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are entering color names in code as: Black, Green.

And we are keeping images in server as: black.png, green.png

In site instead of color names, its displaying related image.

Now we need to enter color as "Bright Pink**, for that when we gave color name   bright pink.png in server, it's not displaying image in site.

Issue: For one word color, its displaying image, but not for 2 word colors.

Script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    varinner=Array();
    inner=jQuery(".product-options ul.options-list .label>label");
    for(i=0;i<inner.length;i++){
        varclassN=inner[i].innerText;
        if(classN=="Black"||classN=="Green"||classN=="Bright Pink"){
            inner.eq(i).addClass("colors");
            classN=classN.toLowerCase();
            varurlB="http://sitename.com/media/catalog/custom/"+classN+".png";
            inner.eq(i).css('background-image',
            'url('+urlB+')');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space are not allowed in URLs. So encode the spaces it the file name it  should work

Try

```
   classN = encodeURIComponent(classN.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to escape (percent-encode) the spaces in your URL as `%20` using:

```
text.replace(/ /g, '%20')
```

If you post your HTML, I can add it to the snippet below to verify its correctness. I also made some changes using regular expressions and jQuery utility functions to help reduce the size of your code; please let me know if you have any questions.

```js
jQuery.fn.ready(function() {
  var inner = jQuery('.product-options ul.options-list .label > label')
  inner.each(function () {
    var text = this.textContent.toLowerCase()
    if (/^(?:black|green|bright pink)$/.test(text)) {
      var url = 'http://sitename.com/media/catalog/custom/' + text.replace(/ /g, '%20') + '.png'
      jQuery(this).addClass('colors').css('background-image', 'url(' + url + ')')
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```